# Parameterized number of cycle delays in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have to delay a few control signals in a pipeline I've designed by the number of stages in the pipeline.  This is obviously very straight forward -- just put N flip-flops in between the the input signal and output signal.  I'm wondering if there's a way to parameterize N.  If I ever change the number of stages in the pipeline I have to go back and add/remove flip-flops, which is sort of annoying.  I thought about just writing a script to read a define somewhere and generate the module, but that seems like overkill.  Is a genvar loop the right way to go here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to created the parameterized shift register using a generate block and a DFF module. It even **works with DEPTH=0 and DEPTH=1**.

```
module shift
(
  input clk,
  input reset,
  input data_in,
  output data_out
);

parameter DEPTH = 3;
wire [DEPTH:0] connect_wire;

assign data_out = connect_wire[DEPTH];
assign connect_wire[0] = data_in;

genvar i;
generate
   for (i=1; i <= DEPTH; i=i+1) begin
      dff DFF(clk, reset,
        connect_wire[i-1], connect_wire[i]);
   end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

Complete working code with a test on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/50

Comment: Is it possible to generalize this to dynamic DATA_WIDTH as well? (instead of just single bit DFF) The genvar seems troublesome.

Comment: Yes, you could use another parameter DATA_WIDTH. The dff module would need to support it. For the shift module, you could use a multi-dimensional array for connections `wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] connect_wire [DEPTH:0];`

Answer (score 8):

You could use a parameterized shift register to do this.  Something like:

```
module shift
(
  input clk,
  input data_in,
  output data_out
);

parameter DEPTH = 3;
reg [DEPTH-1:0] holding_register;

always @ (posedge clk) begin
  holding_register <= {holding_register[DEPTH-2:0], data_in};
end

assign data_out = holding_register[DEPTH-1];

endmodule
```

Another alternative would be to use a generate statement to create essentially the same effect.

Comment: Here is the working code and test on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/49